# Center tool tip on each country

Tags: leaflet, react, tooltip

[image]

I'm trying to center the tooltip with the name of the country so it will show at the middle of the country but they are all over the place.

```
import { MapContainer, GeoJSON, useMap } from "react-leaflet";
import "./Map.css";
import { useState, useEffect } from "react";
import * as ReactDOMServer from "react-dom/server";
import "bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css";



const Map = (props) => {
  const [modal, setModal] = useState(false);
  const [countryData, setCountryData] = useState({});
  const [center, setCenter] = useState([50.832915, -3.146892]);
  const [zoom, setZoom] = useState(4);

  
  const countryStyle = {
    fillColor: "#A7BEAE",
    color: "white",
    weight: 0.2,
    fillOpacity: 1,
  };

  const onEachCountry = (country, layer) => {
    const map = useMap();
    const name = country.properties.ADMIN;

    layer.bindTooltip(name, {
      direction: "center",
      permanent: true,
      className: "labelstyle",
    });
    layer.on({
      mouseover: (event) => {
        event.target.setStyle({
          fillColor: "#B85042",
        });
      },
      mouseout: (event) => {
        event.target.setStyle({
          fillColor: "#A7BEAE",
        });
      },
      click: () => {
        console.log("hello")
      },
    });
  };

  return (
    <>
      <div>
        <MapContainer
          style={{ height: "100vh" }}
          zoom={zoom}
          center={center}
          minZoom={2.3}
          maxZoom={6}
        >
          <GeoJSON
            style={countryStyle}
            data={props.countriesData}
            onEachFeature={onEachCountry}
          />
        </MapContainer>
      </div>
    </>
  );
};

export default Map;
```

Comment: Please do not put the whole question in the title, but rather in the body of the question and there also explain what do you mean by "it doesn't work"

Comment: @TomazicM first time here :) edited

Comment: Some countries that are comprised of several separate parts have geometry defined as multipolygons. In the case of multipolygon features Leaflet puts tooltip in the middle of the last polygon that comprises multipolygon. For example in the case of USA these are Hawaii.